# JQuery fadeIn fadeOut smooth issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have following code which i use for fadeIn and fadeOut on hover state.

```
$(function(){
    $("#bottomIco ul li a").hover(function(){
        $(this).children("#gray").fadeOut("100",function(){
            $(this).parent().children("#actual").fadeIn("100");
        });
    },function(){
        $(this).children("#actual").fadeOut("100",function(){
            $(this).parent().children("#gray").fadeIn("100");
        });
    });
});
```

It works, but when i hover in #gray there comes blank and then #actual div comes.

I need to make it smooth i.e. there need not to come blank while i hover.

Comment: sample markup would help a lot

Comment: if possible then pls provide an jsfiddle example and css as well

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get "blank", is because you're fading in `#actual` on the callback of `#gray`'s fade out. Which means you're waiting for `#gray` to fade out completely, then fade in `#actual`.

Try to do fadeout and fadein simultaneously.

```
$(this).children("#gray").fadeOut(100);
$(this).children("#actual").fadeIn(100);
```

Since both fades runs async, they will be executed at about the same time, a millisecond or two lag, maybe.

The only thing you need to consider when doing this is that they will both render to the screen at the same time, so if you want a fading transition, you need to look into positioning.

```
#bottomIco ul li a { position: relative; }

    #bottomIco ul li a.fade #gray,
    #bottomIco ul li a.fade #actual {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

Then just apply and remove the `fade` class when you're fading between.

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.addClass("fade");
$this.children("#gray").fadeOut(100);
$this.children("#actual").fadeIn(100, function() {
    $this.removeClass("fade");
});
```

Comment: @PushparajJoshi What isn't working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: i get blink in between two images. i will show you in jsfiddle

Comment: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/ This makes my problem solved. Thanks a lot you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think using CSS3 would be a more elegant solution. Can you post a jsfiddle so I can put it together for you?

Comment: Here is a CSS only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/yyzr4/2/  Please let me know if I have understood the problem!